# How does one clear user input in Bash when using 'read'?

Tags: bash, input

I have this code in an infinite loop:

```
read -a output
echo ${output[@]}
```

When the code runs the screen might look like this:

```
Hello, World # line where value was given to output (I want this gone)
Hello, World # echoed output
[] # <-- cursor waiting for next input
```

Is there a way to clear the line where the user inputs the value? Like, as in get rid of it totally (not just changing the line to whitespace that will still leave a gap in the desired output)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `tput` with the `cuu1` and `dl1` capabilities.

```
echo "foobar42"
echo "$(tput cuu1)$(tput dl1)baz123"
```

Comment: @Jonathan: In some cases it's better to use `el` (erase to end of line) instead of `dl1` (delete line) since the latter will cause text below that line to scroll up. Also, it's not necessary to `echo` the output of `tput` using command substitution. `tput cuu1; tput cr; tput el; echo baz123` (the `cr` ensures that you're at the beginning of the line)

Comment: Thanks, Dennis. The dl1 method left unwanted characters before the text after I redirected it to a log file. Your way works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just remove the `echo ${output[@]}`? Since you're not quoting your array variable, this seems to be the same result as if you were to use `tput` hax.

Comment: The actual output isn't just ${output[@]}, there is additional formatting stuff concatenated to the contents of the array. Thanks, though.